# Basis and transcendental basis

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, extension-field, transcendental-numbers

I need to have really good picture in my mind about transcendental basis and What are the similarity between basis and transcendental basis. Let $\mathbb R$  be the set of all really number. Let $\mathbb B$ be a basis of $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$ so it is a maximal linear independent set and  it spans all element of $\mathbb R.$ Also, each element of $\mathbb R$ can be written as linear combination of finitly many element of $\mathbb B.$

Let $T$ be a transcendental basis of $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$ so it is a maximal algebraically independent set. Also, $\mathbb Q(T)=\mathbb R.$

**Is it true that each element of $\mathbb  R$ can  be spanned by finitely number algebraically independent elements of $T$? if so, why.**

**Can we choose for each element of $\mathbb R$ different element of $T$ that spans it?  if so , why ?**

**what we can also say about $T$?**

I hope from those that have a deep understanding for this subject to say more about transcendental basis and algebraically independent set?

Any help will be appreciated greatly

Comment: What is your definition of a "transcendental basis"?

Comment: 1. What do you mean spanned? 2. Trivially no, why do you think this should happen? 3. What do you mean "what can we say about $T$"? What properties do you care about? Coda: stop tagging these questions about transcendence bases with [algebraic-geometry] unless they're about algebraic geometry, please.

Comment: @RobertShore, transcendental basis is the maximal algebraically independent set

Comment: @KReiser, write each element of $\mathbb R$ as finitely linear combination of transcendental basis

Comment: Then trivially not! For $t\in T$, take $t^2$ - if this was a finite $\Bbb Q$-linear combination of other elements of $t$, this would give an algebraic dependence relation among the elements of $T$. -1, please show some more effort next time.

Comment: @KReiser, Okay, why transcendental basis is important ?

Comment: If $T$ is a transcendency basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, then you can say that $\mathbb{R}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(T)$, but equality need not hold. It can happen that $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{Q}(T)$ for some transcendency basis; but if you replace one element of $T$ with its square and denote by $T'$ the resulting set, then $T'$ is a transcendency basis as well, but $\mathbb{R}\ne\mathbb{Q}(T')$.

Comment: @egreg, Thank you for your answer, I was wondering if there is an example about transcendental basis of $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$

Comment: @00GB No, you need the axiom of choice in order to prove its existence.

Comment: @egreg, I know that by assuming axiom of choice each algebraically independent can be extended to transcendental basis. One more question, why transcendental basis is important ?

Comment: @00GB It has relevance in algebraic geometry, for instance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117569/discussion-between-00gb-and-egreg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is it true that each element of $\mathbb R$ can be spanned by finitely number algebraically independent elements of
$T$ ?**

"Spanned" in the sense of linear combination, no.  But any element of $r \in \mathbb R$ is a rational function of finitely many elements of $T$.  That is what $\mathbb R = \mathbb Q(T)$ means.  So linear combinations are not enough.  Starting with $T$, you have to allow products and quotients as well as sums.

**Can we choose for each element of $\mathbb R$ different element of
$T$ that spans it?**

This seems nonsensical to me.  I do not know what "$r$ is spanned by $t$" means, where $r$ is a real number and $t$ is one element of $T$.

**What can we say about $T$?**

From $\mathbb R = \mathbb Q(T)$ it follows that $T$ is uncountable.

Comment: GEdgar, for each $r\in\mathbb R$ there exist $t_1,t_2,\dots,t_n\in T$ such that $r=\frac{f(t_1,t_2.\dots,t_n)}{g(t_1,t_2.\dots,t_n)}$ where $f,g$ are polynomials

Answer (score 3):

You're conflating transcendence basis and vector space (Hamel) basis.

If $K$ is an extension field of $F$, there exists a set $T$ consisting of transcendental elements of $K$ such that

1. $T$ is algebraically independent;
2. $K$ is algebraic over $F(T)$.

Such a set is a *transcendence basis* of $K$ over $F$.

A set $U\subseteq K$ is algebraically independent if and only if, for every finite subset $S=\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$ (elements pairwise distinct) of $U$, there is no nonzero polynomial $f(X_1,\dots,X_n)\in F[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ such that $f(a_1,\dots,a_n)=0$.

Using a technique very similar to the proof of existence of vector space basis, one can show that a transcendence basis exists and that any maximal algebraically independent set is such a basis; also, two transcendence bases have the same cardinality.

So let $T$ be a transcendence basis of $K$ over $F$. It is not possible to prove that $K=F(T)$, when $T$ is a transcendence basis. To see why, consider the simple case when $K=F(t)$, where $t$ is transcendental over $F$; then also $\{t^2\}$ is a transcendence basis, but clearly $K\ne F(t^2)$. On the other hand, $t$ is algebraic over $F(t^2)$, so $K$ is indeed algebraic over $F(t^2)$. Perhaps more simply, if $K$ is algebraic over $F$, then the empty set is a transcendence basis, but $K$ need not equal $F$.

In general, if $T$ is nonempty transcendence basis and you replace one of its elements, say $t$, by its square $t^2$, then the set $T'$ so obtained is still a transcendence basis, but definitely $F(T')\subsetneq F(T)$. So condition 2 above cannot be replaced by $K=F(T)$.

In the finite case $K=F(t)$ it is certainly false that a transcendence basis is also a vector space basis: indeed, $K=F(t)$ is infinite dimensional as vector space over $F$.

In the case of $F=\mathbb{Q}$ and $K=\mathbb{R}$ a transcendence basis must have the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, by a cardinality argument: we have
$$
\mathbb{Q}(T)=\bigcup_{\substack{S\subseteq T\\S\text{ finite}}}\mathbb{Q}(S)
$$
and every subfield $\mathbb{Q}(S)$ is countable.

Also a vector space basis has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, but a transcendence basis cannot be a vector space basis. Let $T'=T\setminus\{t\}$, where $t\in T$ is fixed. Then $\mathbb{Q}(T)=F(t)$, where $F=\mathbb{Q}(T')$. Then $\mathbb{Q}(T)$ is infinite dimensional over $F$. If you remove one element from a vector space basis, the subspace spanned by the new set has codimension one.

What you can say is that every $r\in\mathbb{R}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}(S)$, where $S$ is some finite subset of $T$. Indeed, if $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $r$ over $\mathbb{Q}(T)$, it has finitely many coefficients, so it belongs to $\mathbb{Q}(S)[X]$, for some finite $S\subseteq T$.

For completeness, $\mathbb{R}$ is not a purely transcendental extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, that is, for every transcendence basis $T$ of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Q}(T)\subsetneq\mathbb{R}$. Indeed if equality holds, any permutation of $T$ would induce an automorphism of $\mathbb{R}$, but $\mathbb{R}$ has only the identity automorphism.

Comment: egreg, Thank you so much. If there is any books or lectures that you recommend that help me to have better understanding for this subject

Comment: @00GB I learned it on Jacobson's Basic Algebra II

Comment: Does this also say that there is no Hamel basis of $\mathbb R$ as a vector space over $\mathbb Q$ which consists only of transcendental numbers?

Comment: @PaulFrost I'm not sure. Possibly.

Comment: @egreg,  I have a question. Let $H$ be a hamel basis of $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q.$ Let $B\subset  H$ such that $H\setminus B$ is infinite. Now, $\Bbb Q(B\cup A)\not\subset\Bbb Q(H)=\Bbb R$ for every finite set $A\subset H.$ Is that true? If so, it is obvious and  not require proof. Right?

Comment: @00GB My impression is that it’s false. If it’s true, it definitely needs a proof. I guess you mean $\mathbb{Q}(B\cup A)\subsetneq\mathbb{Q}(H)$

Comment: egreg. Do you mean $\mathbb Q(H)=\Bbb R$?  Not correct

Comment: @00GB Of course $\mathbb{Q}(B\cup A)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, so your notation needs a fix (or an explanation of what you mean by $\not\subset$). Anyway, take the set of powers of $\pi$, $\{1,\pi,\pi^2,\dotsc\}$ and complete it to a Hamel basis $H$. Take $B=\{\pi^2,\pi^3,\dotsc\}$. Then $H\setminus B$ is infinite, but $\mathbb{Q}(B)=\mathbb{Q}(H)$.

Comment: egreg, why $H\setminus B$ in your example is infinite

Comment: @00GB Because $H$ is uncountable and $B$ is countable.

Comment: @egreg, in your first comment, I thought you agreed that   $\Bbb Q(B\cup A)\subsetneq \Bbb Q(H)$

Comment: @00GB Not at all. I just tried to find a sense in the notation.

Comment: @egreg, I am still confused, to be honest. Anyway, correct me if I am wrong. $ \Bbb Q(H)=\Bbb R.$

Comment: @00GB Yes, that's true. So what? My example shows that $\mathbb{Q}(B)=\mathbb{Q}(H)$ so also $\mathbb{Q}(B\cup A)=\mathbb{Q}(H)$ for every subset $A$ of $H$.

Comment: @egreg, I think , I saw this on a transcendental basis, I mean, Let $T$ be the transcendental basis and $B\subset T$ such that $T\setminus B$ is infinite. Then, $\Bbb Q(B\cup A)\subsetneq \Bbb Q(T).$  Is that right? Or still wrong as well.

Comment: @00GB Transcendence basis and Hamel basis are very different beasts. If $T$ is a transcendence basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, then $\mathbb{Q}(B)\ne\mathbb{Q}(T)$, for every *proper* subset $B$ of $T$.

Comment: @egreg, This means the property that I mentioned from the beginning works for a transcendental basis not for a Hamel basis. right?

Comment: @00GB Yes. And there's no need to assume $T\setminus B$ is infinite. Just that $B\cup A\ne T$.

Comment: @egreg, I did not think how it can be proved. Is the proof straightforward ? or it is already in the textbook.

Comment: @00GB It's the definition of transcendence basis, isn't it? A *maximal* algebraically independent set. Any proper subset would not be maximal, would it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126508/discussion-between-00gb-and-egreg).

Comment: @egreg. How are you doing. I posted a question related to algebraically independent. I was wondering if you have an idea about it. Here is the question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4195659/707884. Thank you